# Does anyone know which textbook this question is from? $\displaystyle \int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t+1}dt > 0$ for all $x>0$

Tags: integration, reference-request

So I'm currently doing integration problems preparing for final exam, and I would like to practice problems like the following:

Prove that $\displaystyle \int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t+1}dt > 0 \ \ $ $\forall x>0$

Can anyone tell me which textbook it is from?

Comment: I don't no why it's important to know which textbook it is from. It might be in a lot of books. Which  topic does it concern would be a more appropriate question and what are some good books on this topic. Do you agreee with me ? Just wanted to make things clear

Comment: @PandaBear I just wanted to know if anyone knows the exact textbook for this problem..I have alot of other textbooks but im just interested in this one.Understand?

Comment: @ChrisK wow thanks alot man, you were right..I found it in Spivak.

Answer (score 4):

This is from Apóstol's Calculus Vol I. I don't have it with me right now, I can update with the precise page.

**ADD** A slick solution is to integrate by parts, letting $u=1-\cos t$, $v=(1+t)^{-1}dt$ so that

$$\begin{align}\int_0^x vdu=\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{1+t}dt &=uv\mid_0^x-\int_0^x udv\\&=\frac{1-\cos x}{1+x}+\int_0^x\frac{1-\cos t}{(1+t)^2}dt>0\end{align}$$

Comment: I found the page.Thanks!

Comment: @user142472 You're welcome. You may upvote answers you find useful, and accept the answer you think best answers your question.

Comment: It's also in Spivak. I ordinarily prefer the proof indicated by @Srinivasa, as it is more elementary. As I recall, the problem occurs in both books quite early on, before integration techniques.

Comment: @TedShifrin I wonder who put that problem in there...

Answer (score 3):

There is no universal textbook for problem like these. Below is how you would prove such a problem.

Let $m$ be the largest integer such that $2\pi m \leq x$. We then have
$$\int_0^x = \int_{2m\pi}^x + \sum_{n=0}^{(m-1)} \int_{2 n \pi}^{(2n+2)\pi}$$
It suffice to show that
$$\int_{2m\pi}^x  \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t+1} dt > 0 \text{ and } \int_{2 n \pi}^{(2n+2)\pi} \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t+1} dt > 0$$
Further, note that $$\int_{2 n \pi}^{(2n+2)\pi} \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t+1} dt > 0 \implies \int_{2m\pi}^x  \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t+1} dt > 0 \tag{$\star$}$$
$(\star)$ is because if $x \in [2m\pi, (2m+1)\pi)$, the integrand is positive and if $x \in [(2m+1)\pi,(2m+2)\pi)$, then
$\displaystyle \int_{2m\pi}^x  \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t+1} dt > \int_{2 m \pi}^{(2m+2)\pi} \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t+1} dt$.

Hence, it suffice to prove that
$$\int_{2 n \pi}^{(2n+2)\pi} \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t+1} dt > 0$$
\begin{align}
\int_{2 n \pi}^{(2n+2)\pi} \dfrac{\sin(t)}{t+1} dt & = \int_{2n \pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t+1} dt + \int_{(2n+1) \pi}^{(2n+2)\pi}\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t+1} dt\\
& = \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi} \underbrace{\left(\dfrac1{t+1} - \dfrac1{t+\pi+1} \right)\sin(t)}_{>0} dt
\end{align}
where the last step is obtained by changing the variable $t \to x+\pi$ in the second integral and hence proved.

Answer (score 0):

The integral involves special functions known as [trigonometric integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral), but the problem become quite trivial after you know those functions. Those functions are introduced in most books under the name "mathematical methods for physicists" or similar books for other fields.

Are you taking a introductory calculus course or more advanced?

Comment: I'm taking an advanced calculus course..with problems like these..I already have the solution to this particular problem..but I would like to find similar integral problems.

Comment: MIT OCW usually has some nice problem sets: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/#cat=mathematics&subcat=calculus Recommended textbooks are also included.

Comment: What on Earth does "MIT OCW" mean? Can we just drop unnecessary acronyms and write in full sentences?

Comment: It's "MIT Open Courseware."